# Does Ruby on Rails 4 automatically set the Cache-Control: no-cache HTTP Header for 301 redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rack, http-caching

If so, is this documented somewhere?

A little more detail:

My controller action renders a 301 redirect, like so:

```
def show
  redirect_to "/some-url", status: 301
end
```

When I inspect network traffic for this request in the browser, it appears that rails automatically sets the Cache-Control: no-cache HTTP header for 301 redirects.

Comment: It seems that you've answered your own question (yes, it does... you have evidence of it).  Where the documentation would be is off topic for SO, but is there some other question you want to ask?  For example, do you want to change the value of the header for one (or all) 301 redirects?

Comment: From a quick glance at the Rails source, I would say that Rails always set no-cache on all dynamic content, and that 301 redirects are not treated special.

Comment: I also noticed this now, and I didn't expect this. I wanted my 301s to be cached and not hit server again!